# Changing z-index and width but section clears siblings not overlap?

Tags: jquery, html, css

At the click of a box I want one of the `section`s to "pop-out" overlapping its `siblings` (similar, I guess, to a modal). But instead of overlaying the others it clears them, pushing itself down or the others beneath it. I'm not sure where to go and googling z-index has just resulted in finding a bunch of people who forgot to set `position`.

[I made a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rjxei) so you can see what's happening (header omitted).

Adjusting the `bottom` of `full-width` can work to move it where I want, but I'm not sure that there isn't a way to have it find the upper left corner of its parent on its own, especially when screens can be lots of different sizes.

Comment: Add `position: absolute !important;` to your `full-width` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `top:0` and `left:0` to define the upper left corner of a parent.

I think I managed to get the effect you want by adding this to the `.full-width` class:

```
position:absolute !important;
left:0px;
```

Basically, position absolute takes an element out of the page flow, so siblings and its parents no longer take it into consideration for their own positions and dimensions.

Comment: What if he doesn't want the section to always be at the absolute left. Also you should avoid `!important` as much as possible. You'd be better off replacing `.full-width` with `.container.full-width `

Comment: Then he can just change the left position to something else, or remove it entirely and change for margin. But he did specifically mention that he wondered how find the upper left corner of a parent element. I think it's fair to assume he meant for this particular question.

Comment: @herezy You're right about the effect I am going for, but to add to my tool belt what are you referring to by "change for margin"

Comment: As for the use of `!important`, while I agree that it should be avoided when possible, it doesn't mean it can't be used at all.His code already uses it to overwrite `width`, so I think it just makes sense to set another declarations in the same way, when they're used for the same effect.

Comment: @MCB Sorry, hadn't seen your comment. Instead of left, which positions the element according to the left of its positionned parent, you can also use margin (or margin-left, margin-top, etc) to position it according to its default position.